# onActivityResult never invoked within Activity part of ActivityGroup

Tags: android

I'm using a TabActivity that calls an ActivityGroup. Tipical approach that brings problems.

Now I'm facing a problem with onActivityResult

in my Activity I have..

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.place_buttontab_community_media);

        Button ButtonClick =(Button) findViewById(R.id.addPicture);
 ButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener (){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                // request code

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

            }
        });

}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(TAG, "hi");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

unfortunately onActivityResult is never invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen for the result in the ActivityGroup's onActivityResult(). When a result is received, you have to decide which Activity should receive it and call it's onActivityResult() method with the received values.

Comment: yeah, not only I had to place onActivityResult on the ActivityGroup class but I also had to call MyActivity.this.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST); ... The new Activity must be triggered by the parent to work properly.

Comment: Yes that's what I ment when I wrote "dispatch it" :)

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this, to consolidate Andras' and virtual82's answer and discussion above (Sorry I can't add comment due to my low rep):

If your activity is started inside an ActivityGroup, which is used by TabActivity for example, then only the ActivityGroup activity can receive method calls to onActivityResult when you start an activity with startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) from an activity inside the ActivityGroup.

In my situation, I have a TabActivity that contains FragmentActivitys. A Fragment inside a FragmentActivity may start an activity for result.
In this case the Fragment needs to start the activity with TabActivity as the calling activity:

```
Intent doSomethingIntent = new Intent();
//getActivity() returns the FragmentActivity, so we need to get the TabActivity with getParent()
Activity tabActivity = getActivity().getParent();
doSomethingIntent .setClass(tabActivity , PostCommentActivity.class);
tabActivity.startActivityForResult(doSomethingIntent , DO_SOMETHING_REQ_CODE);
```

Then in onActivityResult of the TabActivity, pass the result back to the Fragment.

```
Activity currentActivity = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
//get the FragmentActivity in order to get the Fragment instance
if(currentActivity instanceof FragmentActivity){
    FragmentActivity currentFragmentActivity  = (FragmentActivity)currentActivity ;
    //R.id.l_container is the layout/viewgroup that contains the Fragment
    Fragment currentFragment = currentFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.l_container);
    if(currentFragment != null){
        //pass result to the Fragment!
        frag.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

I realize that ActivityGroup, TabActivity and LocalActivityManager are deprecated in favor of Fragment and FragmentManager, but my project time constraint didn't allow me enough time to fully upgrade.
Hopefully this post will help someone in this situation, instead of the usual "don't do it" kind of response you see else where.